# Functions called in incorrect sequence, or earlier call was unsuccessful

Tags: apache-flex, action

in my application,

I did some trace statements of a file

For example

```
if(oldFile.parent.toString()!=file.parent.toString())
```

There are some other file print statements , and it seems to encounter this error stated below.
But the error does not appear every time. For example i ran my application for 20 times, it will encounter this error once.

`Error: Error #2037: Functions called in incorrect sequence, or earlier call was unsuccessful.
at Error$/throwError()
at flash.filesystem::File/resolveComponents()
at flash.filesystem::File/get parent()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you are not checking the existence of the file before calling it. Refer this [link](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/02/28/error-error-2037-functions-called-in-incorrect-sequence-or-earlier-call-was-unsuccessful/) might be help full.

Comment: nope does not work.  i tried with the code below 
`
if(oldFile!=null){
trace("oldFile : "+oldFile.exists.toString());
}
`

it still show the error at the trace statement

Comment: Hi, its abit difficult to that, cause there are like few thousand lines of codes. The oldFile is a private variable that is initialize in the whole program. Is this error very common in AS3 ?

Comment: not like that once we see the code, it will be easy to find out the issue